# Pronunciation of "majorant"

Tags: pronunciation

> I just looked up [majorant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/majorant) to see IPA and found none. I googled, and found [this](https://www.howtopronounce.com/majorant/), which has what sounds like `/'mæ.dʒɔ.ɹənt/`, `/mə:'dʒɔ.ɹənt/` and `/'meɪ.dʒəˌɹæənt/` to my ears, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEEcq57lCKk), which also has `/'meɪ.dʒəˌɹæənt/`, then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzpQ0mNpJ10), which sounds like `/'meɪ.dʒɔ.rənt/`, [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/majorant), which has explicit IPA as `/ˈmeɪdʒər(ə)nt/`, and then I got fed up of looking :). I do not know how to classify these pronunciations, nor if there are nonstandard ones, so could someone read these and put them into the article with appropriate classification (and perhaps narrower IPA)?

I posted the above [on the Wiktionary Tea Room](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Tea_room/2017/May#Pronunciation_of_majorant) on May 7. Nobody answered, so I thought I could post it as a question here. How do you pronounce *majorant*? Which of the above IPA matches which accent, and which (if any) are nonstandard?

PS I personally would have gone for `/'mæ.dʒəɹ.ənt/`, but I just wanted to be sure, hence I checked the Wiktionary.

Comment: Your first sound link sounds nothing like /ˡmædʒɔɹənt/ or /ˡməːdʒɔɹənt/ unless I'm missing something. He clearly says _major ant_ (as you notice, as two words), which sounds odd. /ˡmeɪdʒərənt/ is the only pronunciation that occurred to me, and also the only one I can find in any dictionaries. Definitely the one I'd go with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the first link has three audios matching the three IPAs in order from top to bottom. And yes, the last sample _could_ be "major ant", come to think of it.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that block further down on the page. I'd only seen the one at the top (it's quite a cluttered page on a phone). The first two of those sound like synthesised speech, i.e., computers. The first one is definitely not a human voice. The last one sounds human, but probably over-enunciating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematics, the only way I have heard *majorant* and *majorize* pronounced is as *major* with a suffix. So

> /ˈmeɪdʒərənt/ and /ˈmeɪdʒəraɪz/.

Wiktionary says *majorant* comes from French (the French verb is *majorer*; *majorant* is derived from it), while the OED says it was formed in English from *major* + *-ant*. So people who know the French word and have just seen the English written might easily pronounce it /ˈmædʒərənt/, as /æ/ is probably the closest English vowel to the French pronunciation.

ADDENDUM: (Etymology) Looking at the chronology, it looks like, for the mathematical usage, Wiktionary is probably right. The verb *majorer* in French means to *overvalue*. I assume that French mathematicians used the word *majorer* and the derived word *majorant* in mathematics; the mathematical meanings are quite similar to *overvalue*. Then English borrowed the mathematical term *majorant* (in 1925), and this was re-verbed to form *majorize* (1934). The word *majorize* (from *major* + *ize*) was a rare word in English before, with quite different meanings. [To come of age; to put a piece of music into a major key; to convert a try into a goal in Rugby.]

Comment: What is the last paragraph a TL;DR of?

Comment: The question wasn't about the etymology. It was just about the pronunciation.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering what that paragraph was a TL;DR of. TL;DR should mean (AFAIK) that there is a longer version somewhere, but it is not clear where. As is, the last paragraph, in my opinion, would be better termed as an Addendum or Extra than as a TL;DR.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has

> Pronunciation:
>     Brit. /ˈmeɪdʒər(ə)nt/
>   ,  U.S. /ˈmeɪdʒərənt/